# How to set up types for react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my React typescript project I have this code:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const background = location.state && location.state.background;
  ...
}
```

Typescript complains that "***Property 'background' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)***"
How should I expand Location type and make ts happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since react-router-dom useLocation do not accept a generic props as `useLocation<{background: boolean}>` anymore, you can apply the same solution that Redux Toolkit does with useDispatch and useSelector and simply extend them to add an interface. Here's an example :

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import type { Location } from "react-router";

// T is to make a generic type so you can use it wherever you want. Feel free to export in into another common types file.
interface LocationWithState<T> extends Location {
  state: T;
}

interface LocationState {
  background: boolean;
  foo: number;
}

export function App() {
  const location = useLocation() as LocationWithState<LocationState>;
  const background = location.state.background; // works ✅
  const foo = location.state.foo; // works ✅
  const bar = location.state.bar; // error ❌
}
```